# Finding specific alternative form of $\frac{(x-y)x+{y\over(y-z)}}{(x+y)z}=ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does one approach; $$\frac{(x-y)x+{y\over(y-z)}}{(x+y)z}=ab$$ to find the form:  $$-a b z (x+y) (y-z) = x^2 (-y)+x^2 z+x y^2-x y z-y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(x-y)x+{y\over(y-z)}}{(x+y)z}=ab$$
take LCM on upper part
$$\frac{(x-y)(y-z)x+{y}}{(x+y)(y-z)z}=ab$$
$${(x-y)(y-z)x+{y}}=ab(x+y)(y-z)z$$
$$-({(x-y)(y-z)x+{y}})=-(abz(x+y)(y-z))$$
$$-({(xy-xz-y^2+yz)x+{y}})=-abz(x+y)(y-z)$$
$$-({x^2y-x^2z-xy^2+xyz+{y}})=-abz(x+y)(y-z)$$
$${-x^2y+x^2z+xy^2-xyz-y})=-abz(x+y)(y-z)$$
$${x^2(-y)+x^2z+xy^2-xyz-y})=-abz(x+y)(y-z)$$